# Width, padding giving auto in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to coding for padding, width based on previousSibbling Div id.
Based On Prev Div id's Width, Padding, I will calculate current width,padding. It is working in Mozilla. But IE PrevSibbling Div's Width, padding coming as "auto" and i tried to add 10px to width. But it is not working. Div functionality working as "auto" properties only.
  Please suggest me. Code is too simple. two simple divs only.

Comment: LOL...... try to answer your own question from our perspective. We don't know what you tried... what Adam said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... the question isnt terribly clear.  BUT, if its what I think it is, make sure you have a proper DOCTYPE set in your html file.  IE will adjust how it handles CSS based on that.  Without a DOCTYPE, 'auto' will not work in IE the way it does in FF, and some of the spacing behaves differently.  So try adding something like this to the top of your html file, if you dont already have it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jQuery `innerWidth()` or `outerWidth()` methods, you'll get real width information. IE7 is just uncooperative.